# creating sql function in Postgres, too many commands

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am creating my first sql function as I want to call the same query multiple times but just change the months

Here is my function

```
create function sevRun (string,int,int)
returns int
stable
as $$
SELECT count(*) from (
SELECT case_id,
FROM dbname.tablename 
WHERE create_date >= TO_DATE('2017-$1-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND create_date < TO_DATE('2017-$2-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND min_impact <= $3
AND assigned_to_group IN ('listitem1','listitem2',...)
end
$$language sql$$;
```

And then I try and call the function

```
select sevRun (01,02,2);
```

However I get the following error

```
Invalid operation: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement;
```

I am guessing I have to many `SELECT` queries inside the call. I just want to count the number of rows returned by my select query but I want to run the query for each month.

Comment: Remove the final double dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems here.

1. The final `$$` will mess things up
2. You end `plpgsql` functions with `end` but don't do that with SQL functions.
3. Your subquery is missing the closing parenthesis
4. Your subquery needs a table alias since it is the from clause.
5. Your variable interpolation is broken
6. Did you mean (string, string, int) or (Int, int, int)?  Because you seem inconsistent.

Your function should look like:

```
create function sevRun (string,int,int)
returns int stable as $$
SELECT count(*) from (
    SELECT case_id,
      FROM dbname.tablename 
     WHERE create_date >= TO_DATE('2017-' || $1 || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
           AND create_date < TO_DATE('2017-' || $2::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           AND min_impact <= $3
           AND assigned_to_group IN ('listitem1','listitem2',...)
) inline_view
$$language sql;
```

Comment: I have added my code for review i now get the error `Invalid operation: The select expression can not have aggregate or window function.;`

Comment: Good to ask another question in that case.